# Use font awesome icon for tabbed page tabs

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabs, icons, font-awesome, tabbedpage

This is how I add tabs to a tabbed page.
I have Font awesome icons working at various places in my app. How do I add icons to my tabs, since I add tabs in the code behind like this:

```
public partial class MainTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
    public MainTabbedPage(SelectedItem item)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var summaryPage = new DeviceSummaryPage(item);

        Children.Add(summaryPage);
        Children.Add(new DeviceSettingsPage(item));
        Children.Add(new FirmwarePage(item));       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I add icons to my tabs

First, you need to copy the fonts to the platform-specific projects:

1. on Android into the **Assets folder** with **Build Action** **AndroidAsset**,
2. on iOS into the **Resources folder** with the Build Action **BundleResource**,
3. on UWP into the **Assets folder** with Build **Action Content**.

Note:On iOS, a change to the Info.plist file is required so that the added fonts can also be used.

The png is on Android Platform.

[image]

In order to be able to use the fonts, creat ResourceDictionary in App.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
        <OnPlatform x:Key="FontAwesomeBrands" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Regular" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome5Brands-Regular" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Font Awesome 5 Brands" />
        </OnPlatform>

        <OnPlatform x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Regular" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome5Free-Solid" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
        </OnPlatform>

        <OnPlatform x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular" x:TypeArguments="x:String">
            <On Platform="Android" Value="FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Regular" />
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="FontAwesome5Free-Regular" />
            <On Platform="UWP" Value="/Assets/FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Font Awesome 5 Free" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

Create a FontImageSource object and set the values accordingly then pass this object to the IconImageSource of your ContentPage.

```
  public TabbedPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var solidFontFamily = Application.Current.Resources["FontAwesomeSolid"] as OnPlatform<string>;
        var RegularFontFamily = Application.Current.Resources["FontAwesomeRegular"] as OnPlatform<string>;


        Children.Add(new simplecontrol.Page1() { IconImageSource=new FontImageSource() { FontFamily = RegularFontFamily, Glyph = "\uf108" } });
        Children.Add(new simplecontrol.Page3() { IconImageSource = new FontImageSource() { FontFamily = solidFontFamily, Glyph = "\uf108" } });

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I was just looking for this part ` Children.Add(new simplecontrol.Page1() { IconImageSource=new FontImageSource() { FontFamily = RegularFontFamily, Glyph = "\uf108" } });`